# How to get file object for corresponding dentry object | linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

Suppose I have a pointer to dentry object, how can I obtain its corresponding file object?

I need this  to enforce some security policy in my LSM.

Comment: Object `struct file` is **created** only when you open the file. Do you mean `struct inode` object instead?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need the file object? If you have a legitimate use for it, the relevant LSM hook most likely takes it as an argument.

There is no "guaranteed" file object for a dentry. It may so happen that the dentry represents a file which is opened by a given process. Except process can have it opened multiple times and in effect you can have multiple file objects, now what?